# Unbiased estimator of the variance

Tags: variance, unbiased-estimator, estimators, statistical-learning

I am going through the book *[The Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)* and I'm finding it extremely terse. I have a background in probability but not statistics so perhaps that is why. Anyway, in Chapter 3, section 3.2 (p.47), they discuss the unbiased estimator of the variance of the $y_i$. They write,

> Typically one estimates the variance $\sigma^2$ by
>   $$ \hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{N − p − 1} \sum_{i = 1}^N ( y_i − \hat{y}_i)^2.$$
>   The $N − p − 1$ rather than $N$ in the denominator makes $\hat{\sigma}^2$ an unbiased estimate of $\sigma^2$.

Here the $y_i$ are the observations which we assume are distributed like 
$ x_i^T \beta + \zeta_i$, where $x_i$ are the inputs, $\zeta_i$ are independent of everything, mean zero, variance $\sigma^2$, and $\beta$ is fixed. $\hat{y}_i$ are the estimated output from the linear regression we have constructed. Ie., $\hat{y}_i = x_i^T \hat{\beta}$ with $\hat{\beta}$ the linear multiplier, $\hat{\beta} = (X^T X)^{-1}X^T y$.

They make this comment without any explanation. Can someone explain why this is true. And even better, why this should be obvious.

Edit: Thanks to @gung for the link but I found that calculation still unclear and missing details. I'm putting down my calculation here just for completeness.

Some notation: Let $X$ be the $N \times (p+1)$ matrix of samples by characteristics (the extra $1$ is for the column of all ones!). Let $y = (y_1,...,y_N)$ and $\hat{y} = (\hat{y}_1,...,\hat{y}_N)$.

Under these conditions, $\hat{y} = X \hat{\beta}$ and $y = X \beta + \zeta$ where $\zeta$ is an $n\times 1$ vector of independent Gaussians with common variance $\sigma^2$. Using our formula for $\hat{\beta}$ above this gives
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T y = \beta + (X^TX)^{-1}X^T \zeta \\
\end{align}
$$
And so, 
$$
\begin{align}
y - \hat{y} & = X\beta + \zeta - (X\beta + X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \zeta) \\
& = (I_N - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T) \zeta \\
& := (I_N - B) \zeta,
\end{align}
$$
with $B:= X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbb{E} (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2 & = \mathbb{E} \left[(y-\hat{y})^T(y-\hat{y}) \right] \\
& =\mathbb{E} \left[ \zeta^T (I_N-B)^T (I_N-B) \zeta \right] \\
& = \sigma^2 Tr((I_N-B)^T(I_N- B)) .
\end{align}
$$
The last equality follows because the $\zeta$ are *independent* with common variance $\sigma^2$. 
Finally,
$$
\begin{align}
(I_N-B)^T(I_N-B) &= I_N - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T. \\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
Tr((I_N-B)^T(I_N-B)) & = Tr(I_N) - Tr(X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T) \\
& = Tr(I_N) - Tr(I_{p+1}) \\
& =N-p-1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: As you might guess, this is basic and so many answers have been provided in passing in many threads: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=bias%20estimate%20variance.  I have found an apparent duplicate that contains the relevant calculations.

Comment: It's not so much obvious as well known - to people with a background in Statistics.

Comment: @Scortchi. I see. So if it is well known, do you know of a good source to find the calculation?

Comment: I think any textbook on regression would include this result.

Comment: I just found this writeup. It's extremely good. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24921/distribution-of-sum-of-squares-error-for-linear-regression