# If I have only $(\pmb{X}'\pmb{X})^{-1}$, how can I find $\pmb{X}$ (the design matrix)?

Tags: multiple-regression, matrix, linear-algebra

My teacher gave me a problem, but he only give me the $(\pmb{X}'\pmb{X})^{-1}$ matrix.

If I have **only** $(\pmb{X}'\pmb{X})^{-1}$, how can I find $\pmb{X}$ (the design matrix)?
I think this is an algebra problem, but now I can't think a solution.

Comment: $\frac 1 {x^2} = 1$, $x$ can be 1 or -1.

Comment: I didn't understand why you simply sayed this. Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: Think $x$ is 1 $\times$ 1 matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in general impossible. $(X^TX)^{-1} \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times k}$ and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ with
$n > k$. There are many matrices $K \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$ such that  $(K^TK) = (X^TX)$. Do you know something else about X?

Comment: My teacher gave us the SSE (say 200) and the number of observartions (say 15). He want the unbiased $\sigma^2$. I thought use the fact of $\frac{SSE}{n-k} = \hat{\sigma}^2$, but he wants this in matrix form!

Comment: Is SSE sum of squared errors?

Comment: Yes, SSE is the sum of squared errors

Comment: Both SSE and the variance are numbers, not matrices. You need $\frac{SSE}{n-k}$. That part with the matrix form is probably just a confusion.

Comment: Yes, I used this in my exam, but he sayed we should have used a matrix way.

Comment: Did the guy ask for a value, or for the derivation of the estimator?

Comment: If he asked for the derivation, how would be this?

Comment: See here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24921/distribution-of-sum-of-squares-error-for-linear-regression

Comment: I know that $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{\pmb{y}^T(\pmb{I} - \pmb{H})\pmb{y}}{n-p}$, but I can't figure out how to achieve this from $(\pmb{X}^T\pmb{X})^{-1}$

Comment: Sorry, I mean $n-k$

Comment: What else do you know about the components of $X and about (X^TX)^{-1} ?

Comment: @igor given your comments your question seems to omit relevant information. Please edit to describe the circumstances.