# Proof that regression residual error is an unbiased estimate of error variance

Tags: self-study, least-squares, standard-error, proof

Consider the least squares problem $Y=X\beta +\epsilon$ while $\epsilon$ is zero mean Gaussian with $E(\epsilon) = 0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I need to prove that

$\frac{V(\hat{\beta})}{N-(n+m)}$ is an unbiased estimate of $\sigma^2$ with $V(\beta) = ||Y-X\beta||$ .

I wasn't able to find the answer online.  I just got confused by a thousand different ways to write things down.

EDIT:
$Y = \begin{pmatrix} y(0)\\ \vdots \\ y(N-1)\end{pmatrix} \quad$
$X = \begin{pmatrix} x^T(0)\\ \vdots \\ x^T(N-1)\end{pmatrix}\quad $ 
$\beta = \begin{pmatrix} a_1\\ \vdots \\ a_n\\ b_1 \\\vdots \\ b_m \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: What are N, n, and m?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question

Comment: I still don't quite follow your $n$ & $m$, & the way you are representing the matrices is unusual for me. I'm more familiar w/:$$Y=\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\ \vdots\\ y_N\end{pmatrix},\quad X=\begin{pmatrix}1 &x_{11}&\cdots&x_{1p}\\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\ 1 &x_{N1}&\cdots&x_{Np}\end{pmatrix},\quad\beta=\begin{pmatrix}\beta_0\\ \vdots\\ \beta_p\end{pmatrix},\quad\varepsilon=\begin{pmatrix}\varepsilon_1\\ \vdots\\ \varepsilon_N\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: The notation was given to me (at the university), but it is quite the same as x are vectors and p=m+n..

Comment: On the basis of this comment combined with details in your question, I've added the `self-study` tag. Please read its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and understand what is expected for this sort of question and the limitations on the kinds of answers you should expect. While you can ask about course-related work (or even work you're just doing for your own study purposes), CV isn't a site to just do your study for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following your notations, we have $$V(\hat{\beta}) = \|\hat{\epsilon}\|^2 = \text{RSS}$$ i.e., the Residual Sum of Squares.

It is a fact that (cf. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20227/why-is-rss-distributed-chi-square-times-n-p/20230#20230)) $$\frac{\text{RSS}}{\sigma²} \sim \chi_{(N-p)}^2$$ with $N$ the total sample size and $p$ the number of parameters in $\beta$ (here, $p = n + m$).

The result follows from the fact that the expectation of a chi-square random variable equals its number of degrees of freedom, i.e.,
$$
\text{E}\left(\frac{\text{RSS}}{\sigma²}\right) = N - p
$$
which can be rewritten as 
$$
\text{E}\left(\frac{\text{RSS}}{N-p}\right) = \sigma²
$$
since $N-p$ and $\sigma²$ are both non-random.

Comment: I cant follow why $V(\hat{\beta})$ is $||\hat{\epsilon}||^2$. What exactly is $\hat{\epsilon}$?

Comment: $\|v\| = \sum_{\ell=1}^L v_\ell^2$ for any vector $v=(v_1 \dotsc v_L)$. Thus
$V(\hat{\beta}) = \|Y - X \hat{\beta}\|$ is the sum of squared residuals, which I have denoted by $\|\hat{\epsilon}\|$.