# Covariance of a random vector after a linear transformation

Tags: covariance

If $\mathbf {Z}$ is random vector and $A$ is a fixed matrix, could someone explain why $$\mathrm{cov}[A \mathbf {Z}]= A \mathrm{cov}[\mathbf {Z}]A^\top.$$

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For a random (column) vector $\mathbf Z$ with mean vector $\mathbf{m} = E[\mathbf{Z}]$, the covariance matrix is defined as $\operatorname{cov}(\mathbf{Z}) = E[(\mathbf{Z}-\mathbf{m})(\mathbf{Z}-\mathbf{m})^T]$.  Thus,
the covariance matrix of $A\mathbf{Z}$, whose mean vector is $A\mathbf{m}$, 
is given by
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{cov}(A\mathbf{Z}) 
&= E[(A\mathbf{Z}-A\mathbf{m})(A\mathbf{Z}-A\mathbf{m})^T]\\
&= E[A(\mathbf{Z}-\mathbf{m})(\mathbf{Z}-\mathbf{m})^TA^T]\\
&= AE[(\mathbf{Z}-\mathbf{m})(\mathbf{Z}-\mathbf{m})^T]A^T\\
&= A\operatorname{cov}(\mathbf{Z})A^T.
\end{align}$$