# Multivariate Gaussian distribution explanation needed

Tags: probability, self-study, covariance, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am pretty new in statistics. I Googled the multivariate Gaussian distribution, but still have no idea how to solve this.

[image]

I tried to make $\mu_{x} \rightarrow  a\mu_{x} \ and\, \mu_{y} \rightarrow  b\mu_{y}$, is this the answer?

$\left ( X,Y \right )\sim N(\mu,\sum )\\
\mu =\begin{bmatrix} \mu _{x} \\ \mu _{y} \end{bmatrix}  \ and \,
 \sum= \begin{bmatrix}
 a^{2}\mu_{x}^{2}& abCOV[X,Y]\\
 abCOV[X,Y]& b^{2}\mu_{y}^{2}
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Almost all problems on this site are statistics problems. Consider making your title more informative.

Comment: This question deserves the `self-study` tag. Please add it and detail your reasoning to solve the problem and the reasons why you cannot derive the covariance matrix.

Comment: You could find an answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113700/covariance-of-a-random-vector-after-a-linear-transformation

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the `[self-study]` tag & read 
[its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. 
We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: So, can I just change COV[X,Y] to abCOV[X,Y]?