# How to find standard error in multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, standard-error

I know how to find standard error in single regression, but in multiple regression there is more than one standard error and I don't understand what to do. I searched constantly but I couldn't find it.
For example, how can the standard error here be found separately for x,m and constant? I would be very happy if you could help me.[image]

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485676/meaning-of-standard-error-of-the-coefficients-in-a-regression-model

Comment: `Coefficients Std. Error` column?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Do you mean a) Why are there three standard errors in the output?   b) What do any of them mean? (see the link Christoph supplied).  c) Can you get one SE for the whole equation? d) What is the formula for the SEs given in the table? Or e) Something else?

Comment: What is the formula for the SEs given in the table? yes that's exactly what i mean

Comment: I'm calculating manually, not with spss, so I don't fully understand it.

Comment: Please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=formula+regression+standard+error+score%3A5) for the answers.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/623575/how-does-r-lm-function-calculate-standard-error-of-slopes-with-more-than-one-p/623580#623580