# Why a T-statistic needs the data to follow a normal distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, t-test

I was looking at [this notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/pmarcelino/comprehensive-data-exploration-with-python), and I am puzzled by this statement:

> When we talk about normality what we mean is that the data should look
>   like a normal distribution. This is important because several
>   statistic tests rely on this (e.g. t-statistics).

I don't understand why a T-statistic needs the data to follow a normal distribution.

Indeed, Wikipedia says the same thing:

> Student's t-distribution (or simply the t-distribution) is any member
>   of a family of continuous probability distributions that arises when
>   estimating the mean of a normally distributed population

However, I don't understand why this assumption is necessary.

Nothing from its formula indicates to me that the data has to follow a normal distribution:

[image]

I looked a bit on [its definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) but I don't understand why the condition is necessary.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The information you require is in the "Characterization" section of the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Characterization). A $t$-distribution with degrees of freedom $\nu$ may be defined as the distribution of the  random variable $T$ such that
$$T = \dfrac{Z}{\sqrt{V/\nu}} \,,$$
where $Z$ is a standard normal distribution random variable and $V$ is a $\chi^2$ random variable with degrees of freedom $\nu$. In addition, $Z$ and $V$ must be independent. So given any $Z$ and $V$  that follow the above definition, you can then arrive at a random variable that has a $t$-distribution.

Now, suppose $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ is distributed according to a distribution $F$. Let $F$ have mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Let $\bar{X}$ be the sample mean and $S^2$ be the sample variance. We will then look at the formulae:

$$\dfrac{\bar{X} - \mu}{S/\sqrt{n}} = \dfrac{\frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}}{\sqrt{\frac{(n-1)S^2}{(n-1)\sigma^2}}} \,.$$

If, $F$ denotes the normal distribution, then $\bar{X} \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$, and thus $\frac{\bar{X} - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \sim N(0,1)$. In addition, $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-1}$ by [Cochran's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem). Finally, by an application of [Basu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basu%27s_theorem), $\bar{X}$ and $S^2$ are independent. This then implies that the resulting statistic has a $t$-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

If the original data distribution $F$ was not normal, then, the exact distribution of the numerator and denominator will not be standard normal and $\chi^2$, respectively, and thus the resulting statistics will not have a $t$-distribution.

Comment: I've always found it quite interesting how much mathematical technology go into these foundational results in mathematical statistics.

Comment: Good post. However, we don't need to invoke those big theorems to prove the independence between $\bar{X}$ and $S$, as well as the $\chi^2$ distribution. See [the first answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312337/easy-proof-of-sum-i-1n-leftz-i-barz-right2-sim-chi2-n-1) of this post.

Comment: Great answer! Will come back to this later!

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the earlier responses something I think is relevant to the question, albeit possibly only indirectly: The normality of the data as pointed out in the answers is both necessary and sufficient for the *t*-statistic to have a *t*-distribution (hence, a characterization of it as a *t*-distributed random variable) because the normality of the data also characterizes the independence of the sample mean and sample variance (see, e.g., [Lucaks (1942). A characterization of the normal distribution. *Annals of Mathematical Statistics*, **13**(1), 91-93](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-13/issue-1/A-Characterization-of-the-Normal-Distribution/10.1214/aoms/1177731647.full)), which is crucial to the *t*-statistic having a *t*-distribution.  An investigation of the necessity and sufficiency of the normality of the data for the *t*-distribution in this case is provided in [Chen and Adatia (1997), "Independence and *t* distribution," *The American Statistician*, **51**(2), 176-177](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00031305.1997.10473956?casa_token=itr25niuaScAAAAA:Ee8mnV80jWqNeFWAdK-2rsGPOnk9fJ9Y-l1ymXJ6FoAPog0DsTQPhN23GyPFUiRiAKbNaa9AF6k).

Answer (score 2):

I think there may be some confusion between the statistic and its formula, versus the distribution and its formula. You can apply the t-statistic formula to any dataset and get a "t-statistic", but this statistic will not be distributed according to the student-t distribution unless the data came from a normal distribution (or at least, will not be guaranteed to be; my guess is that non-normal distributions won't produce a student-t distribution when the t-statistic formula is applied, but I'm not certain of that). The reason for this is simply that the distribution of the t-statistic is calculated from the distribution of the data that generated it, so if you have a different underlying distribution, then you're not guaranteed to have the same distribution for derived statistics.

Answer (score -3):

All that is needed is that $\bar{X}$ is normally distributed. If $\bar{X}$ is exactly normally distributed (not approximately normal) then the $X_i$ are normally distributed, $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ is chi-square distributed and independent of $\bar{X}$, and $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)}{S}\sim T_{n-1}$.  If $\bar{X}$ is only normally distributed asymptotically there is no guarantee that $\bar{X}$ and $S$ are independent nor that $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ is chi-square distributed, but $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)}{S}\overset{asymp}{\sim}N(0,1)$ and of course a $T_{n-1}$ distribution and a $N(0,1)$ distribution are indistinguishable asymptotically.

Below is a histogram of $X_1,...,X_{100}\sim Gamma(2,3)$ with mean $\mu=2\times 3=6$, and below that is the sampling distribution of $\bar{X}$.

[image]

[image]

Of course the sample standard deviation is not independent of the sample mean as evidenced by the scatter plot below.

[image]

Nevertheless, the sampling distribution of $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)/S$ is well approximated by a $T_{n-1}$ distribution, i.e. $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)/S\overset{asymp}{\sim} T_{n-1}$.

[image]

For the distribution of $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)/S$ to be exactly $T_{n-1}$ distributed *for any sample size* then $X_i$ must come from a normal distribution.

Comment: What about the distribution of the denominator? and the independence of the numerator and denominator?

Comment: Again, this can be achieved asymptotically.  Of course having subject-level observations that are indeed normally distributed provides the required distribution of the denominator as well as the independence of the numerator and denominator, even in small sample sizes.

Comment: Sorry, it's just not true, certainly not only due to the numerator being asymptotically normal. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.14530.pdf for some recent details. No one is saying that the t test is not at all robust to violations of assumptions--it's just much less robust than you realize and your arguments are flawed

Comment: What I have written is not at odds with your arguments.  If $\bar{X}$ is exactly normally distributed, then so too are the $X_i$ and the t-statistic follows a $T_{n-1}$ distribution.  If $\bar{X}$ is normally distributed asymptotically, then the t-statistic is asymptotically $T_{n-1}$ distributed.

Comment: Most people would agree that if $\bar{X}$ is asymptotically normally distributed then the t-statistic is asymptotically standard normal.  Most people would also agree that a t-distribution is indistinguishable from a standard normal distribution asymptotically.  Is it a minor technicality that precludes me from saying the t-statistic is asymptotically t-distributed if $\bar{X}$ is asymptotically normally distributed?

Comment: Geoffrey, I think you're missing the point. You're not wrong due to some minor technicality. Perhaps you could write a question on when it is appropriate to use a t test if you're like to know more?

Comment: I stand by my first statement - all that is needed is that $\bar{X}$ is normally distributed (not approximately).  *This implies that* $X_i$ is normally distributed, $(n-1)S^2/\sigma^2$ follows a chi-square distribution and is independent of $\bar{X}$, and the $t$ statistic follows a $T_{n-1}$ distrbution.  I have added these details to my answer.  Please tell me how any of this is wrong and what point I am missing.  If you have downvoted my answer, please undo it.

Comment: I hope your last few days have gone well. Geoffrey, I highly encourage you to ask a question on this side. Perhaps the title could be "To what extent is the $t$ test robust to nonnormality?".