# Am I using confidence intervals correctly here?

Tags: confidence-interval

I run a stochastic computer program.

What I’m doing is testing one strategy against what might be considered a default strategy. At the start of a run, there are 100 individuals using the test strategy and 100 using the default strategy.

A strategy is successful if the quantity of individuals using the test strategy is significantly greater than the starting quantity of 100 by the end of the run. (There are always 200 individuals: test quantity + default quantity = 200. So when test quantity gains, default quantity loses.)

Each of the 10000 runs will have perhaps 300 time-steps. I will graph a quantity for each of the 300 time-steps, and on the graph, this quantity for each time-step is averaged over the 10000 runs.

Most individual values for quantity will be either 0 or 200, and this is especially true for values closest to the last time-step (e.g., 0, 200, 0, 200, 200, 75). So the distribution of values for a particular time-step may be sort of V-shaped.

And I will be most interested in reporting whether the average quantity for the last time-step significantly exceeds 100.

Since I don't know the population's standard deviation, I use a student’s t distribution.

For 95% confidence intervals, it’s $mean \pm standard\_error*t_{df}$.

And $t_{df}$ for 10,000 runs for 95% is 1.96. So, it’s $mean \pm standard\_error*1.96$.

And the average quantity at the end of a run is significantly greater than 100 if $mean-standard\_error*1.96$ exceeds 100.

Does this look right?

Thank you so much for your time.

Also, I am willing to pay for a person's time.  But I have found that the feedback and insight on this website probably exceed freelancer sites. I truly do appreciate your time.

Comment: In general, yes this is how to calculate a "Wald" confidence interval.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: To those reading these comments: Since num_39's comment, I have modified the question at the suggestion of other users.

Answer (score 1):

**t confidence interval.** Checking your 95% interval, using R as a calculator. Because the population standard deviation $\sigma$ is unknown (estimated by $S)$
it should be the t interval $(91.13, 119.67),$ instead of a z interval. If you have $n = 10\,000,$ then the z and t intervals will be almost indistinguishable.

These methods assume that data are nearly
normal. Is that realistic?

```
y = c(100, 80, 92, 110, 120)
a = mean(y);  s = sd(y)
a;  s>     a;  s
[1] 100.4
[1] 15.51773
CI = a + qt(c(.025,.975), 4) * s/sqrt(5)
CI
[1]  81.13219 119.66781
```

The same CI is provided by the procedure 't.test' in R:

```
t.test(y)$conf.int
[1]  81.13219 119.66781
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

If you have no idea of the population distribution (other than that its standard deviation exists) and a sample of at least
several dozen, then you might try a 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI.

**Non-normal data.** Consider the following $n = 100$ observations sampled in R from a gamma
distribution.

```
set.seed(2022)
x = rgamma(100, 4, 1/40)
summary(x);  length(x);  sd(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   27.4   108.8   150.3   153.4   199.2   431.5 
[1] 100          # sample size
[1] 68.84051     # sample SD
```

**Bootstrap CI.** As above, if you knew the distribution, you could find numbers
$L$ and $U$ such that $P(L < d = \bar X - \mu < U) = 0.95,$
so that a 95% CI for $\mu$ would be of the form
$(\bar X - U, \bar X - L).$

Not knowing $U$ and $L,$ we can take many (e.g. 2000) re-samples of size $n$ with replacement from the data, to get useful approximate values for $U$ and $L,$ as in the brief R program below.

```
set.seed(316)
d = replicate(2000, mean(sample(x, 100, rep=T)) - 153.4)
LU = quantile(d, c(.975,.025))
153.4 - LU
  97.5%     2.5% 
139.3501 166.1383
```

So the a 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI for $\mu$ is
$(139.4, 166.1.)$

If we knew the data are from a gamma distribution
we might be able to find an exact theoretical 95% CI for
$\mu.$ In our case the sample is reasonably large and
the data are not far from normal, so the t interval
$(139.8,\,167.0)$ is approximately correct (but maybe not as good as
the bootstrap CI.)

```
t.test(x)$conf.int
[1] 139.7023 167.0212
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

*Notes:* (1) Because data are simulated in R, we know that the mean $\mu$ of the gamma population is $\mu = 160,$ contained in both CIs.
Of course, in a real application we would never know
the value of $\mu$ for sure.

(2) It is important to understand that the *re-samples* help
to analyze the data `x`, but do not provide additional information about the population.

Comment: Bruce, I really thank you very much for taking the time.  So, re-samples help to analyze the data but do not provide additional population.  Does that mean it's just as advisable to conduct an analysis on a single 10,000 run sample as it as to analyze ten 1,000 run samples on the same population?

Comment: Up to a point, larger numbers of re-samples give more accurate nonparametric bootstrap CIs. Especially for 'small' samples there is not much difference in results if you use a huge number of re-samples. As a generic guideline, I have seen 2000 as a recommended number of re-samples. // I ran the bootstrap of my Answer with 5000 re-samples and got $(139,166)$ again. Same again with 10,000 re-samples. // One bootstrap with 2000 re-samples should suffice. (As you're getting started, maybe do a second run with 2000 with the same data and a different seed--as a reality check.)

Comment: Thank you, sir.  If I'm not mistaken, what I'm trying to do is not nonparametric.  I'm seeking to put a confidence interval around the mean quantity, not trying to assess the whole distribution.  

Based on feedback I've received, I have made a new post that attempts to give more context:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568508/does-this-usage-of-confidence-intervals-look-okay
    
I really appreciate your time and feedback.

Comment: It's called 'nonparametric' when you don't know the population dist'n. For example if pop dist'n were normal you could use t confidence interval to get CI for the unknown pop mean. // There are also parametric bootstraps for situations in which you do know the pop dist'n type, but that dist'n is a "messy" one for which there is no useful formula for the CI (or the known formula is considered too ugly to use.

Comment: Thank you.  So, if I could explain what I'm doing with a bit more detail.  There will be 10000 runs of the program.  Each run will have perhaps 200 time-steps.  I will graph a quantity for each of the 200 time-steps, and on the graph this quantity for each time-step is averaged over the 10000 runs.  Most individual values for quantity will be either 0 or 200, and this is especially true for values closest to the last time-step (e.g., 0, 200, 0, 200, 200, 75).  And I will be most interested in reporting whether the average quantity for the last time-step *significantly* exceeds 100.

Comment: Not everyone reads Comments. Maybe you will get additional points of view if you put that information at the end of your Question.

Comment: Yes, sir.  I have added these details to my updated question which is here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568508/does-this-usage-of-confidence-intervals-look-okay  I'm not going to update this question because the other (updated) one has greater detail.  

And the reason I have added these details is because you talked about knowing whether the distribution is approximately normal.  And it occurs to me it would probably be sort of V-shaped with many values of 0 and many values of 200 but an average around 100.

Comment: Okay I have modified this question.  Thank you.

Comment: Bruce, again, I really appreciate your time.  Regarding what you said, "These methods assume that data are nearly normal. Is that realistic?"  

Do data have to be nearly normal to use a t confidence interval if I use a large (e.g., 10000) number of program runs?

Comment: Often t tests work OK for huge sample sizes. Some elementary texts would have you believe 30 is large enough, but that's simply not true. How big is enough depends on the nature and degree of non-normality. // It is important for $\bar X$ and $S$ (num and denom of t) to be nearly independent. (To spotlight one frequently used dist'n,: for exponential data, they're not.)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but the mean and stdev of the sample are not independent if there are values that depart widely from the mean in a particular direction, i.e., if there is a skew in the sample?  

The data aren't in a normal distribution.  It will have many values of 0 and many values of 200 but the average will probably be slightly above 100.  So, the data should be V-shaped or U-shaped.  But I don't believe it will be heavily skewed.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is **only for normal data** that sample mean and variance are independent.

Comment: See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319754/why-a-t-statistic-needs-the-data-to-follow-a-normal-distribution/541573#541573).

Comment: Thank you Bruce.  You mentioned texts.  Do you recommend any good ones?

Comment: Best to get recommendations for texts from profs who know you and your program.

Comment: I appreciate it, but I'm actually not in a program.

Comment: OK then. Briefly, what highest level stat, prob, math courses have you had so far and from what texts? What objectives for study from next text? Self study? What likely career path? Will let you know if I have recommendations. // Snooped thru your Qs. Please put some info in your Profile for the site.

Comment: I feel I have pretty good command over calc 1.  I have been going through Statistics (12th ed) by McClave, Statistics (9th ed) by Witte, and Openintro Statistics (3rd ed) by Diez, but I haven't used them in a class.  Those texts had me believe it was OK to use z-tests though. 

I have published 3 papers already and I understand PhD by publication is a possibility, though I have not yet contacted an academic program.  I just feel that these papers need to be written, and I have several more coming.  So I just want to learn what I need to publish them.  They are evolutionary biology papers.

Comment: On the basis of what you have suggested, I need to learn about bootstrapping and nonparametric methods.

Comment: You seem to have interest in biol applications. So maybe start with solid traditional elementary text. By traditional, I men frequentist and not oriented toward machine learning based on interests I see so far. Nothing against Bayesian or machine learning, but my guess is it's best to get traditional structures in mind first. Hardcover book on Biostat by Pagano/Gauvreau is solid, but may be challenging for self-study (make your own outline of key formulas as you go along), If budget is an issue, get used copy of olderst edn. R oriented paperback by Dalgaard (Springer publisher) starts...

Comment: ... with a couple of chapters on using R and has many bio/med examples. Also, I have taught out of Math Stat w/ Appl by Wackerly/ Mendenhall/ Scheaffer (Duxbury). Get used copy of earlier edn, and see if you can also find a student answer manual for that edn. Calculus should be enough math. There are many more recent books on math stat with more modern approaches that you might try later and wilth a stronger math background. // All recommendations, including this one, likely to be mostly matters of opinion and quirky. Everyone has different background, goals, experiences. Wishing you success.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I appreciate your time.