# Why is the expected value of variance different than the expected value of Maximum Likelihood variance?

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, expected-value

The expected value of variance is:

[image]

The expected value of the maximum likelihood of variance is:

$E\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}(X-\mu_{ml})^{2})\right] = \frac{N-1}{N}\sigma ^{2} $

Why does inserting the maximum likelihood of the mean, change the result of the expectation? Or is the term that makes the difference:

[image]

I have the entire mathematical proof in front of me, but I can't seem to intuitively understand why they would be different. Why is the expectation of maximum likelihood, different than the expectation of the data? Am I mixing up the expectation of a set of data and the expectation of multiple samples of data?

Comment: You need to distinguish between the population parameter and the parameter estimate from a sample data. The first formula is to calculate population variance with the population mean, while the second formula is to calculate the sample variance estimate using the MLE mean. Those two means are different things.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/76748/77222

Answer (score 1):

If you have data $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ randomly sampled from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma),$ with $\mu$ known and $\sigma$ unknown, then
$V = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \mu)^2$ has $E(V) = \sigma^2,$ with
$\frac{nV}{\sigma} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n).$ The proof follows directly
from the definition of $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n)$ as the distribution of the
sum of $n$ independent standard normal random variables.

However if $\mu$ is also unknown, then
$S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2,$ where $\mu$ is estimated
by $\bar X = \frac{1}{n} X_i,$ is the usual unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2,$
with $E(S^2) = \sigma^2$ and $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim
\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1).$ Informally, people may say that one degree of
freedom is 'lost' in the estimatiion of $\mu.$ However, a formal proof
requires moment generating functions or a transformation of an $n$-variate
normal distribution.

In the latter case ($\mu$ unknown), some statisticians have argued that it is better to use
$Q = \frac{n-1}{n}S^2$ $= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2$ because, for normal data,
it has a smaller mean squared error than $S^2.$ It is true that $\mathrm{MSE}(Q) < \mathrm{MSE}(S^2),$
but it is not obvious that minimizing MSE is a suitable criterion for choosing the best
estimator. [And if minimizing MSE is to be the criterion, then
$Q^\prime=\frac{n-1}{n+1}S^2$ has even smaller MSE, and both variants are biased.]

Simulations and some graphs:

```
set.seed(626)
m = 10^5;  n = 5
x = rnorm(m*n, 100, 15)
DTA = matrix(x, nrow=m)
v = rowSums((DTA-100)^2)/n
s.2 = apply(DTA, 1, var)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 hdr="CHISQ(5)"
 hist(n*v/15^2, prob=T, br=40, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
  curve(dchisq(x,5), add=T, lwd=2)
 hdr="CHISQ(4), not CHISQ(5)"
 hist((n-1)*s.2/15^2, prob=T, br=40, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
  curve(dchisq(x,4), add=T, lwd=2)
  curve(dchisq(x,5), add=T, col="red", lty="dashed", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

```
mean((s.2 - 15)^2)
[1] 69444.44       # aprx. MSE S^2
q = (n-1)*s.2/n
mean((q - 15)^2)   
[1] 43445.15       # aprx. MSE Q
q1 =(n-1)*s.2/(n+1)
mean((q1 - 15)^2)
[1] 29488.79       # even smaller MSE
```

[image]

It seems that MSE is very heavily influenced by the right tail. Too heavily?

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
 hist(s.2, prob=T, xlim=c(0,max(s.2)), col="skyblue2")
  abline(v=15^2, col="red")
 hist(q, prob=T, xlim=c(0,max(s.2)), col="skyblue2")
  abline(v=15^2, col="red")
 hist(q1, prob=T, xlim=c(0,max(s.2)), col="skyblue2")
  abline(v=15^2, col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```