# Regression distribution of Residuals - Chi square test

Tags: regression, least-squares, chi-squared-test, linear

I'm trying to solve a conundrum but can't figure out where I'm making the mistake.

Let me define the Linear model as
$$ 
    \begin{align}
        y &= X \beta + \epsilon \\
\end{align}
$$

Where $X$ is $N \times k$. Now we define our OLS estimates as
$$ \begin{align}
        \hat{\beta}^{OLS} &=   ( X^{T} X)^{-1}X^{T}y \\\\
        \hat{y}^{OLS} &= X\hat{\beta}^{OLS} =  X( X^{T} X)^{-1}X^{T}y \\\\
        \hat{\epsilon}^{OLS} &= y - \hat{y}^{OLS} = (I - X( X^{T} X)^{-1}X^{T})y
    \end{align}
$$
defining $P$  as the projection matrix $$ P =  X( X^{T} X)^{-1}X^{T} $$ and $M$ as the annihilator matrix $$ M = I - P $$

I can write  $$ \hat{\epsilon}^{OLS} = M y = M (X \beta + \epsilon ) = M \epsilon $$

**Assuming** normal distribution of the residual terms

$$ \epsilon \sim\mathcal{N} ( 0, \sigma^{2}I ) $$

This would give us $$ \epsilon^T \left( Var(\epsilon) \right)^{-1} \epsilon = \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \epsilon^T \epsilon \sim  \chi^2 (N) $$

We should also get
$$ \hat{\epsilon}^{OLS} \sim \mathcal{N} ( 0, \sigma^{2} M^TM ) = \mathcal{N} ( 0, \sigma^{2} M ) $$

Now comes the confusion. We know that

$$  \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \left( \hat{\epsilon}^{OLS} \right)^T\left( \hat{\epsilon}^{OLS} \right) \sim  \chi^2 (N-k) $$

We can see this without going into too much detail as

$$ \begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \left( \hat{\epsilon}^{OLS} \right)^T\left( \hat{\epsilon}^{OLS} \right) &= \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \left( \epsilon^T M^T M \epsilon \right)  \\\\
&= \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \left( \epsilon^T M \epsilon \right) \\\\
&\sim \chi^2(N-k)
    \end{align}
$$
To get to the last step, you can show that $M$ has a $rank$ of $N-k$.

More detail if required can be found here ([Why is RSS distributed chi square times n-p?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20227/why-is-rss-distributed-chi-square-times-n-p))

**However** If something is normally distributed with a mean of 0 then

$$  \begin{align}
    \left( \hat{\epsilon}^{OLS} \right)^T \left( Var(\hat{\epsilon}^{OLS}) \right)^{-1}\left( \hat{\epsilon}^{OLS} \right) \sim \chi^2 (N) 
    \end{align}
$$

Investigating this I get the following
$$  \begin{align}
    \left( \hat{\epsilon}^{OLS} \right)^T \left( Var(\hat{\epsilon}^{OLS}) \right)^{-1}\left( \hat{\epsilon}^{OLS} \right) &=  \epsilon^{T}M^T\left(\sigma^2 M\right)^{-1}M\epsilon \\\\
&= \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \epsilon^{T}M^TM^{-1}M\epsilon \\\\
&= \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \epsilon^{T}M\epsilon \\\\
&\sim \chi^2(N-k)
    \end{align}
$$

So now I'm not sure where I'm making the mistake. I get this contradiction in my notes. Any reference material would be very helpful.

Comment: The conclusion is that $\hat{\epsilon}^{OLS}$ is not i.i.d. Normal with mean zero (the "independent" is important here, although you left it out of the line beginning with *However*.)   You have shown this via a proof-by-contradiction!  In a similar, but simpler, way, we can see this easily by noticing that the residuals have to sum to zero (if there's a constant term in the regression), therefore they can't be independent.